# Python - UnicodeEncodeError - encode('utf-8') with gspread in print fuction

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, gspread

I am trying to run a gspread code, to print information from a google spreadsheet.
The worksheet contains í, ú, and ó characters - which is the reason for the UnicodeEncodeError I get.

I read the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html) and other sources which all tell you to use ".encode('utf-8')" or decode(), but don't know how to implement it in my case together with the print function.

I tried things like:

```
#dsheet = sheet.encode('utf-8')
```

and

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

which had no effect.

I am using python 3 on MacOS.

(The Code works I Removed all the UTF characters manual to see - I just want to know how to work out the encode in the future )

The Code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
# Make sure you use the right name here.
sheet = client.open("Legislators 2017").sheet1

#dsheet = sheet.encode('utf-8')
# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
print(list_of_hashes)
```

The Errors:

```
------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spreadsheet.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(list_of_hashes)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xed' in position 84066: ordinal not in range(128)
------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spreadsheet.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(list_of_hashes)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 398608: ordinal not in range(128)
-------
-------
```

Comment: Firstly, nobody here can reproduce what you do there with the information you provide. At best, it's guessing from similar cases. This is also something you could do yourself: Use the exception message to search on the web for existing, similar problems.

Comment: There's no spreadsheet problem here. You just can't `print` the output to your terminal because your terminal is ASCII-only. Set the console to UTF-8 and set the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable to UTF-8 and it should work fine.

Comment: @bobince yes, exactly I did not where to set it. It really was just normal Terminal window. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem to find it was not the only problem.
I Set the PYTHONIOENCODING to UTF-8 on Mac: just enter:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

In the standard Terminal window. Not in Python Shell!

In this particular case, I used Atom-Runner which still showed the Error.
To Workaround that you can specify the encoding as utf-8 in your code for the system:

```
import sys
import io

sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stderr.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Which did the trick.